# D7 - show field in view only when logged in

Tags: drupal-7, view, admin

I am using the weight module and want to show the weight (position) of each item in the view but only when the user is logged in. How can this best be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're displaying them, but I like to use the [Field Formatter Conditions](https://drupal.org/project/ffc) module when I need to apply permissions to fields when displaying content. Pretty simple.